# Is this line of code not properly escaped?

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="radio" name= <?php echo "<a href ='profile.php?user=$user_id' class='box' style='display:block'> $username  </a>";?> />
```

The above line of code functions correctly when parsed but when run a the closing

```
/>
```

is added at the end. so it produces the appropriate username with radio button, but following the username, for instance instead of

```
michael_jackson
```

I get

```
michael_jackson/>
```

Sorry, I know this is elementary but I'm not seeing what's wrong.

Comment: i also tried encapsulating the whole <?php... ?> section in double quotes, and tried with escaping with backspace but none of it seems to be correct

Comment: What HTML are you *trying* to build with that?  You have an `<a>` element as the `name` attribute of an `input` element?  You're building very broken HTML, the browser is just trying to correct it for you.

Comment: im trying to echo a selectable list of users, i dont know how to do it so i was seeing if that worked, seemed like it almost did

Comment: A "selectable list" as in a `<select>` element?  The first thing you're going to need to do is define the HTML you want to build.  *Then* write the PHP code to build it.  Do you know what actual HTML you want?

Comment: to be honest i dont know what you mean by what HTML i want. i didnt elaborate on that because i assume someone would tell me to ask another question

Comment: You might want to start with some tutorials on HTML and PHP then.  You're trying to write code without knowing what you want that code to *do*.  People here might be able to *guess* what you want your code to do, but that's unlikely.

Comment: i have a page with a search query to search for users. i want to be able to have users search for other users, select them, so they can be included in a form.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to echo the `<a>` element inside the name property of your input.  This isn't valid HTML.

I am assuming you want to have the text for the radio button be a link, so try this instead:

```
   <input type="radio" name="user" /><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $user_id; ?>" class="box"><?php echo $username; ?></a>
```

Also its really personal preference but whenever possible I think it's better to keep the HTML separate from the PHP.

Note: Because I am assuming you want the text to be next to the input I removed the `display:block;` style.